# Issue with some Azure DevOps existing organisation pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I've an issue with two existing pipelines that refuse to queue any build on PR.
Every repository in our organisation has its own build policy on master & release/ branches.

The message in the PR is "1 required check broken: Unable to queue Build".
Others existing pipelines are working correctly.
In these two repositories I can trigger a pipeline build manually but not automatically.

I've tried to deactivate the existing build policy or to delete it and recreate it but without success. When I try to delete the existing pipeline I encounter the error : «TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: .».
I've successfully managed to delete an existing pipeline from an old repository, so I have the permission to delete a pipeline.

Any hint ?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: This issue has not been resolved. I've raised and issue with Microsoft and exchanged some information like API logs.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have selected the do not queue new builds option in your pipeline. It should work normally if you change it to the Enabled option.[image]